# Почему в теге Img одни изображения с белым фоном, а у других белый фон заменён на прозрачный?

Tags: html, img, png

[image: Изображение на сайте]

Все фигуры имеют одинаковый формат png

Comment: Без кода не понятно, но по своему скудному опыту предположу что у данного изображения просто вырезан фон, в просмотре фотографий windows, это не заметно так как там у Всех фон белый, откройте в фотошопе и там сразу будет видно это! Если это не так, то ждём код для разбора

Comment: Дмитрий, да действительно при открытии файла фотошопом был выявлен прозрачный фон.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что формат PNG не гарантирует непременно прозрачного фона. В некоторых картинках фон есть, в некоторых нет. Вот и всё :) обычно просто берёшь прямо в браузере картинку мышкой тянешь drag'n'drop куда-то и сразу понятно есть фон или нет.